# Will GetHashCode method return different result for an object between different AppDomain?

Tags: c#, hash

According to [this Eric](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) blog,

*Rule: Consumers of GetHashCode cannot rely upon it being stable over time or across appdomains.
Suppose you have a Customer object that has a bunch of fields like Name, Address, and so on. If you make two such objects with exactly the same data in two different processes, they do not have to return the same hash code. If you make such an object on Tuesday in one process, shut it down, and run the program again on Wednesday, the hash codes can be different.
This has bitten people in the past. The documentation for System.String.GetHashCode notes specifically that two identical strings can have different hash codes in different versions of the CLR, and in fact they do. Don't store string hashes in databases and expect them tbe the same forever, because they won't be.*

I am using this class,

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double NewPrice { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id ^ (Name ?? "").GetHashCode() ^ (ModelNumber ?? "").GetHashCode() ^ (Sku ?? "").GetHashCode()^ (Description ?? "").GetHashCode() ^ Price.GetHashCode() ^ NewPrice.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I am saving the hash of the product properties object in database for change tracking. Means the hash code will tell me whether the object changed or not. If a hash can be changed between app-domain then what is the other way?

Comment: That's not what `GetHashCode` is for. In fact, this is exactly what you *shouldn't* be using it for. Why not use a `version` column or something like that instead?

Comment: The value of `GetHashCode` isn't allowed to change once the object is created. You **cannot** base it on field/properties that are mutable. The only time that you can base the hash code on properties is when those properties are read only and set in the constructor. Things like dictionaries fail if the hash code changes.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I am saying same object on different AppDomain(or process) or open exe on different day.

Comment: @user960567 - Yes, I know that. But I'm talking about the code you posted in your question. It is wrong to implement `GetHashCode` in that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am saving the hash of the product properties object in database for change tracking.

Don't do that. That's pretty much the *definition* of requiring the hash code to be stable over time. AppDomains are pretty irrelevant to this, to be honest.

If you need some sort of hash which *is* stable, you might want to convert your object to a stable binary representation (e.g. using `BinaryWriter`) and then take a SHA-256 hash of that - because SHA-256 (and similar cryptographic hashes) *are* designed to be stable.

Comment: Sorry but please suggest an example. I am using Console app?

Comment: @user960567: Well I've suggested using `BinaryWriter` to effectively serialize your `Product` object to a byte array - you can then use `SHA256` to get a stable hash of that data. Which part of that is proving to be an issue? (It's fine to do all of this in a console app.)

Answer (score 4):

> I am saving the hash of the product properties object in database for change tracking.

`GetHashCode()` is not suitable for that. It is **not** guaranteed - and actually the algorithm (and thus result) for strings has now changed twice, IIRC - and can now give different results per app-domain, as suggested.

But more: it **doesn't tell you about all changes**. A hash code difference tells you about non-equality, but getting the *same* hash-code **not** tell you about equality. It is not required to.

You would need to use a reliable known repeatable hashing algorithm for this; perhaps the SHA1 hash of some serialized form, where the serialization result it itself guaranteed to be reliable. Note: this *still* wouldn't be guaranteed to spot all changes, but it would be much much less likely to get collisions.

Comment: An example will be helpful.